# Pesquisa banco utilizando JSF

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Estou programando uma aplicação em JSF, a minha aplicação consegue fazer a função de Gravar e Alterar sem nenhum problema, porém como estou usando a tecnologia Java web agora estou encontrando uma certa dificuldade em realizar uma pesquisa e trazer os dados para um DataTable, alguém teria algo para que eu possa me basear para realizar tal operação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

um data table intera sobre uma lista.
O value do data table tem que ser uma lista do retorno na consulta ao banco. e o atributo var é cada objeto dessa lista podendo acessar assim suas propriedades.

Exemplo:

**Java**

```
class CarrinhoCompraBean { 
  public List<Item> getItems {
    List<Item> items = consultaBanco(idCarrinho);
    return items;
  }
  public static class Item { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

E em seu template, **Html**

```
<h:dataTable id="table1" value="#{carrinhoCompraBean.items}" var="item" >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Item" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.nome}" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Preço" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.preco}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

[javadoc dataTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/dataTable.html)
[datatable primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml)

Comment: Não é mais fácil retornar o `ResultSet` para o `dataTable`?

Comment: Não Patrick, o resultset não é uma lista e os objetos que ele retornam não são pojos. Voce não tem exemplo o getNome no retorno de um resultSet. tempos que transformar resultSet e objetos.

Comment: Se não me engano, o componente `dataGrid` do PrimeFaces permite essa associação, com `ResultSet`.